# Devexpress - Re-bind Chart Control error Index was out of range

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I has using dexexpress chartcontrol and bind the datasource in runtime.

```
chartControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
chartControl1.SeriesDataMember = "Task";
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentDataMember = "Resource";
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Percentage" });
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.View = new StackedBarSeriesView();
```

The first time binding, it has work fine and can show the chart.
When I click a button to re-create the dataset with new row of data, it give me an error in 
chartControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

I has set the dataset = new dataset before fill it again with new data.

Any one has idea what wrong.  Please help.

Comment: You should not have to reset the datasource, just adjust the existing datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something along the lines of the following:

```
        this.chartControl1.BeginInit();
        DataTable chartData = this.chartControl1.DataSource as DataTable;


        DataRow row = new DataRow()
        {
            "col1",
            "col2"
        }

        chartData.Rows.Add(row);
        this.chartControl1.RefreshData();
        this.chartControl1.EndInit();
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that DevExpress occasionally gets confused when I set the DataSource, especially to an existing object. To work round this, before I set the DataSource to anything, I always set it to null first. Since doing that, I have not had any problems.

Give that a try.

Comment: Hi Sab, I has try set the datasource to null before re-bind but it also the same.  Do you has any idea?

Comment: Not sure I want to reply, given that I was down voted for a suggestion! Still, when are you setting the data source to null? Make sure you null it before you re-build the dataset. The error results from the control accessing the datasource while the dataset is being rebuilt.